# Returning a list of non pickable objects with multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a function f that is creating a list of instances of an object X. I would like to run this function using parallel processing, I.e. ideally I would like to start a bunch of processes that will in parallel create these lists based on the parameters they are given. The processes are independent of each other, meaning they don't rely on the output of the other processes and don't exchange any information with each other. I tried using the multiprocessing module for this. Unfortunately the class for X is not pickable. It is provided by a different developer team and it is not possible to get them to make it pickable. I found that the return values of a process run in a multiprocessing pool needs to be pickable and the same is true if I try to use structures like Queue to exchange the data between my processes and the main function.

Is there any solution that would allow me to still use parallel processing?

Comment: Can you convert X into json? Convert it, return the json string or the dict, rebuild the object from json. A little more work to be done compared to pickling it.

Comment: Just to confirm: are the individual processes creating the instances of object X, or are they just making lists out of existing objects? If X cannot be pickled, and the instances need to be created after multiprocessing starts, I don't think there's anything you can do except find some other way to represent/recreate them.

Comment: you're going to want to give more details